# Clean language: read the content of text file to list of lines. Is it possible to avoid Uniqueness?

Tags: functional-programming, clean-language, uniqueness-typing

Assuming I have `*File` that I want to read its whole content, and store each line as different element in a list.

My intuitive solution was:

```
first (x,y) = x

readFile:: *File -> [{#Char}]
readFile file 
    | first (fend (file))   = []
    | otherwise             = [ line : readFile (file)] 
where
    line = first(freadline (file))
```

Both `freadline` and `fend` come from `StdFile` module:

```
/**
 * Reads a line from a textfile, including a newline character, except for     the
 * last line. `freadline` cannot be used on data files.
 */
freadline   :: !*File -> (!*{#Char},!*File)

/**
 * @result Whether end-of-file has been reached
 */
fend        :: !*File -> (!Bool,!*File)
```

But ofcourse I got error since I violated some Uniquness rules:

> file demanded attribute cannot be offerd by shared object.

How to avoid this Uniquness problem?
I've tried using `where` to store the value of one `freadline`, but apparently it doesn't work.

Please consider the fact that I'm new to `Clean` and the rules of Uniqueness are not very clear to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This kind of basic functionality is already covered in libraries, in this case in System.File for instance. See https://cloogle.org/src/#Platform/System/File;icl;line=32-45 for its `readAllLines` function which does what you describe. No, it is not possible (should not be) to circumvent uniqueness typing - it is a *feature* of the type system intended to ensure purity of the language while still allowing mutable updates and I/O manipulation. See chapter 9 of the language report for this.